# Разбор предложения "Только не сжата полоска одна"

Tags: синтаксический-разбор, частица, обстоятельство

Вот тут в предложении

> только не сжата полоска одна

[image: Уроки русского языка]

говорят, что "только" является обстоятельством образа действия: Не сжата как? - только. Звучит как полный бред. По-моему, "только" здесь не относится к глаголу, поэтому нельзя задавать вопрос к нему от глагола, оно относится ко всему предложению в целом.

Нашел в подтверждение такое:

> В предложении **Только над валежником стрекочет синекрылая сойка** слово
>   «только» является выделительно-ограничительной частицей. Её можно
>   убрать, что кардинально не изменит смысла предложения, то есть частица
>   не является членом предложения.

Сойка стрекочет как? - только. Получается что здесь ошибка? 
И какую функцию выполняют частицы вначале предложения если они не являются членами предложения и кардинально не меняют его смысла?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен.

Частица — это **служебная часть речи**. Как и другие служебные части речи (предлоги, союзы), частицы не называют предметы, признаки, действия, а указывают на отношения между ними.

Частицы придают словам  или предложениям **дополнительные смысловые оттенки,** существуют также формообразующие частицы.

Частицы **не являются членами предложений.**

Если посмотреть **в словарь**, то можно увидеть, что слово ***только*** может быть частицей, союзом, наречием. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE&all=x

***....поля опустели,***

***Только не сжата полоска одна...***

В данном случае ***только*** является **союзом-частицей с противительно-ограничительным значением**. Это означает, что во втором предложении ограничивается (сужается) сфера действия, обозначенная в первом предложении: все поля опустели, но одна полоска еще не сжата.

Уступительного значения здесь нет.

Сравнить: ***Тихо*** было все на небе и на земле, как в сердце человека в минуту утренней молитвы; **только** изредка набегал прохладный ветер с востока, приподнимая гриву лошадей, покрытую инеем.

При разборе: *Одна полоска* — подлежащее, *не сжата* — сказуемое, *только* — союз-частица.

Comment: Спасибо. Не думаю что "только" относится с числовому обороту "одна полоска". Вы поэтому исправили? Скорее "только" относится сразу ко всему предложению "одна полоска не сжата", противопоставляя его предыдущему предложению.

Comment: Да, в учебнике посмотрела (Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка"). Там эта тема рассматривается в разделе "сложносочиненное предложение с противительными союзами". Частица выступает в роли союза, поэтому  относится ко всему предложению и стоит в начале предложения.

Answer (score 2):

> Поздняя осень. Грачи улетели,
>  
>   Лес обнажился, поля опустели,
>   Только не сжата полоска одна...

Конечно, "только" здесь частица или союз (союзный аналог), но никак не наречие. Следовательно, членом предложения выступать не может.

Далее. В данном случае "только" можно заменить по смыслу аналогами ***но, вот только***. Значит, мы имеем противительное значение, а не усилительное.

Семантическая структура текста следующая: констатируется, что наступила поздняя осень, это подтверждается многочисленными наблюдениями, но особняком стоит одно несоответствие. Поэтому частица **только** имеет характеристики ограничительного и уступительного значений.

В этом случае частица (союзный аналог) **только** относится к противительно-уступительному типу.

> Только над валежником стрекочет синекрылая сойка

Здесь тоже **только** является противительно-уступительной частицей. Правда, чтобы понять это, нужно видеть предыдущий контекст. Приведу для сравнения похожее по структуре предложение, в котором **только** действительно выступает в роли выделительно-ограничительной частицы:

**Только над мёртвыми так кружатся стервятники**.

Тема частицы **только** очень сложная. Желающим я предлагаю познакомится с ней [по этой научной статье](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/soyuznye-funktsii-chastitsy-tolko-chastitsa-soyuz-vs-chastitsa-soyuznyy-analog/viewer), которая написана достаточно простым языком.

Comment: Спасибо за статью. Хотя еще не читал. Интересные они эти логико-модальные частицы. Первое впечатление от частиц как будто это какой-то мета-язык, оперирующий предложениями, а не членами предложений. Отношение говорящего к предложению. Отношение предложений (противопоставление друг другу итд...)  И кстати, привет c dxd